# Передать URL изображения в input поле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача следующая, у меня есть поле, которое отправляет изображение на почту, мне нужно чтобы на почту отправлялась ссылка на эту картинку. То есть, человек должен получить не картинку, а ссылку на картинку. Нужно передать URL изображения в input поле. Само изображение хранится на хостинге, вот его URL (https://fs.getcourse.ru/fileservice/file/download/a/48939/sc/162/h/dd97ef257509429dfc159e12a7a7266b.png)

Я знаю, что это можно сделать на jquery или обычном js. Но все, что я ищу, не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если и правда нужно всего-то ето

> Нужно передать URL изображения в input поле.

то вот :

```js
function fn() {
  // fing you img tag by some selector
  let img = document.querySelector('img');

  // set img.src as value to some text input 
  document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value = img.src;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="fn()" value="Do It!!!" />
<input type="text" />
<br />
<img src="https://fs.getcourse.ru/fileservice/file/download/a/48939/sc/162/h/dd97ef257509429dfc159e12a7a7266b.png" />
```